# NoMethodError - undefined method path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a NoMethodError `` undefined method `avatar_path' `` that comes from my view on line `<%= button_to('Set as Avatar', [:avatar, @photo])%>`

I am assuming the problem is from the routes, though the changes I have made still did not fix the issue.

The photo it should be making a avatar is `/uploads/photo/image/8/IMAG0090.jpg`

Routes:

```
  resources :photos do
    member do
      post :avatar
    end
  end
```

Photos Controller:

```
  def new 
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    @photo.user = current_user
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photos."
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end



  def resize(width, height, gravity = 'Center')
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.combine_options do |cmd|
        cmd.resize "#{width}"
        if img[:width] < img[:height]
          cmd.gravity gravity
          cmd.background "rgba(255,255,255,0.0)"
          cmd.extent "#{width}x#{height}"
        end
      end
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end

  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    if @photo.update_attributes(paramas[:photo])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated photo."
      redirect_to @photo.gallery
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed photo."
    redirect_to @photo.gallery
  end

  def avatar
    if current_user.update_attribute(:avatar_id, params[:id])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully made Avatar."
        else
          flash[:notice] = "Avatar failed"
        end
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Set as avatar!"
      end
end
```

View (users/show.html):

```
<div class="parent-container">
<% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb)), photo.image_url%>
    <%= button_to('Set as Avatar', [:avatar, @photo])%>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Share the action which renders the view with button.

Comment: Share the `controller action` which renders this view? You are sharing the view not the action.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I never created a show action for the Photos controllers as I did not think it would be needed to set a Avatar.

Comment: You are not getting my question. I am not asking for show action. I am asking for the `action which renders this particular view`. Just share the entire controller. Also, share the name of current view file name.

Comment: Please share the `UsersController` as you are rendering the `users/show` view. You can remove the `PhotosController` from the question as it is not relevant.

Comment: I found the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `users/show` view as below:

```
   <div class="parent-container">
   <% @user.photos.each do |photo| %>  ## Block variable name is photo
      <%= link_to image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb)), photo.image_url%>
      <%= button_to('Set as Avatar', [:avatar, photo])%>  ## photo not @photo
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

There is no `@photo` variable, It should be just `photo` as the Block variable name is `photo`.

Comment: Ah thank you for the fresh eyes. I was going crazy over here. Thanks for the point out!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<%= button_to('Set as Avatar', avatar_photo_path(@photo)) %>
```

Comment: I started with something similar to that but did not work which is why I switch to what I posted here. It doesn't work with my action which is why I can't use it. That sends me to /photos//avatar which it should be setting the photo id and redirecting me back to root url. So it removes the error but it also changed my code so that it doesn't connect with my controller. I added controller to the post as that may help.

Answer (score 0):

you pass symbol :avatar instead of variable

```
button_to('Set as Avatar', [:avatar, @photo])
```

so if you pass variable, rails will take its id by itself.

```
button_to('Set as Avatar', [@avatar, @photo])
```

Comment: I did that before but I had it in reverse with the photo, avatar. The exact format you have sends me a error `Nil location provided. Can't build URI.` The correct photo variable is being loaded... `<Photo id: 6, created_at: "2014-02-20 14:34:33", updated_at: "2014-02-20 14:34:33", image: "IMAG0334.jpg", name: "", gallery_id: "", user_id: 1, avatar: nil>`. I am assuming the error is showing because it is trying to pull up @avatar, which shouldn't exist since the User would be trying to set their avatar from a photo.